# How to create a schema inside a database (database and schema should be dynamic)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried the following SQL code:

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE @CreateSchema NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @dbname = 'abc';
SELECT @Schema = 'sdssd';

SELECT @CreateSchema = N'USE ' + @dbname + '; CREATE SCHEMA ' + @Schema + ' AUTHORIZATION [dbo]' 

EXEC(@CreateSchema);
```

This is results in an error:

> Create Schema must be the first statement in a query batch

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get away with this directly. Though, if you are open to use nested `EXEC`, try following.

```
Declare @Schema varchar(40);
Declare @dbname varchar(40);
Declare @CreateSchema nvarchar(Max);
SELECT  @dbname = 'abc';
SELECT @Schema = 'sdssd';

SELECT @CreateSchema = N'USE '+@dbname+'; EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA '+ @Schema +' AUTHORIZATION [dbo]'')' 
EXEC(@CreateSchema);
```

> FYI - you missed declaring a variable `@Schema` in your sample.